# Identity involving scalar product and cross product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, cross-product

If $\gamma$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ why is the third equality is true?

$$
\begin{split}
\ddot{\alpha}(s(t)) &= \frac{s'(t)^2 \cdot \gamma''(t) - s'(t) \cdot s''(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)}{s'(t)^4} \\
& = \frac{\gamma''(t) \langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle - \gamma'(t) \langle \gamma''(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle}{\left|\gamma'(t) \right|^4} \\
&= \frac{ \gamma'(t) \times (\gamma''(t) \times \gamma'(t))}{\left| \gamma'(t) \right|^4}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with curves. It is just an application of the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product):$$u\times(v\times w)=v\langle u,w\rangle-w\langle u,v\rangle.$$

Comment: I like the term BAC-CAB Identity. It's easier to remember that way.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BAC-CABIdentity.html